# Generating variations of a json object, internal values, based on another value "state"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to generate a json, similar to:

```
'alpha' : {
  "impro": 10,
  "axdo": 20,
  "sendo": 14 
} 
'beta' : {
  "tero": 90,
  "dote": 10,
  "sendo": 14 
}
```

The values, for secondary keys ("impro") are having, 3 states: normal, warning, danger.

```
states = ['normal', 'warning', 'danger']
```

I'm thinking on using classes:

```
 class Alpha:
   def __init__(self):
     keys = ['impro', 'axdo', 'sendo']
     state = random.choice(states) 
     for k,v in keys.iteritems():
        setattr(self, k, generate_value(state=state))
```

`generate_value` is a function that generate a value, based on the `state` that was passed.

I need to create enough random, Alpha objects, to be sure, that each secondary key, was in all 3 states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood the question correctly. Every value of object Alpha is chosen from values that belong to three intervals (`normal`, `warning`, `danger`). I use product to generate all combinations:

```
import random
from itertools import product, cycle
import json

class Alpha:
    keys = ['impro', 'axdo', 'sendto']
    values = {'normal':(0, 100), 'warning':(200, 300), 'danger': (400, 500)}

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Alpha(impro={},axdo={},sendto={})'.format(self.impro, self.axdo, self.sendto)

class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
        def default(self, o):
            return o.__dict__


def generate_objects(cls):
    for p in zip(cycle([cls.keys]), product(cls.values.keys(), repeat=len(cls.keys))):
        c = cls()
        for k, v in zip(*p):
            rand_val = random.randint(*cls.values[v])
            setattr(c, k, rand_val)
        yield c

for alpha in generate_objects(Alpha):
    print(json.dumps({'alpha': alpha}, cls=MyEncoder, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "alpha": {
        "impro": 42,
        "axdo": 24,
        "sendto": 96
    }
}
{
    "alpha": {
        "impro": 75,
        "axdo": 57,
        "sendto": 210
    }
}
{
    "alpha": {
        "impro": 11,
        "axdo": 62,
        "sendto": 478
    }
}

... and so on.
```